# Shell Command to delete all files other than .cpp files

Tags: shell

I want to delete all the files in a directory but not the `.cpp` files.

I need some command like:

```
rm all except .cpp files
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Based on the [suggestion to not parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), you can also loop yourself:

```
for f in *; do if [[ $f != *.cpp ]]; then rm "$f"; fi; done
```

---

Otherwise, something like this could work:

```
ls | grep -v ".cpp$" | xargs rm
```

If you want to do it recursively you can use:

```
find . -type f -not -iname "*.cpp" | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can turn on `extglob` (if you haven't already) by running `shopt -s extglob` and then:

```
rm !(*.cpp)
```

(run `echo !(*.cpp)` to check first!)